# why onchange is not working when i use php with it

Tags: javascript, html

while using php with JavaScript onchange function is not working

```
<input type="text" class="gold" name="second" id="second" placeholder="<?PHP echo $rate_1;>"style="width:150px;text-align: right;"onchange="multiply(this)">
```

Comment: Is `multiply()` a Javascript function. ?

Comment: this is because he change event does not trigger at page load while you are setting php value to input type. You have to trigger change event manually using javascript after page loaded successfully

Comment: yes multiply() is javascript function

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in javascript :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#second').change();
   //or
   $('#second').trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

make sure that you have included `jquery`

Comment: This gets loaded when form loads but the function should be loaded or triggered only when the focus change from that input field